# Cannot update single Composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

My `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "laravel/cashier": "~5.0",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
    "torann/geoip": "0.2.*@dev"
},
```

My `composer show -i`

```
laravel/cashier                       v5.0.14            Laravel Cashier pr...
laravel/framework                     v5.1.29            The Laravel Framew...
```

Newest Laravel/Cashier version is 6.0.
If I run `composer update laravel/cashier` I get

> Nothing to install or update.

If I modify my `composer.json` to `"laravel/cashier": "~6.0"` and run `composer install` I get

> ... Lock file is not up to date ... and Nothing to install or update.

What is the recommended way of updating a package and why wouldn't `composer update larave/cashier` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `composer update` will only update packages within the version constraints you've set in composer.json.

Because you've restricted this package to `~5.0` it won't update to version `6.0`.

First update composer.json to `~6.0` then run `composer update laravel/cashier`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. But is there any way to tell composer to get the latest version without having to change composer.json?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Once you've restricted the version in composer.json, that's the authority. It has to change first.

Comment: The docs for `update` are here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update. I don't see any option to force updating to the latest, in spite of composer.json restriction.

Comment: Okay, at least I know it's not possible via CLI but I learned the proper order of updating!